# How do i add a new div every time i submit form?

Tags: php, html

how do I echo a complete new div and keep old ones that are created from my form every time i submit?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['textTitle'],$_POST['commentText'])) {
file_put_contents("titel.txt",$_POST['textTitle']."\n",FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents("kommentar.txt",$_POST['commentText']."\n",FILE_APPEND);
$titelArray = file("titel.txt");
$commentArray = file("kommentar.txt");

echo '<div>';
echo '<h2>';
echo  $titelArray[count($titelArray)-1];
echo '</h2>';
echo '<p>';
echo $commentArray[count($commentArray)-1];
echo '</p>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the request:

```
if (isset($_POST['textTitle'], $_POST['commentText'])) {

    file_put_contents('titel.txt', $_POST['textTitle']. "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents('kommentar.txt', $_POST['commentText']. "\n", FILE_APPEND);
    $titelArray = file('titel.txt');
    $commentArray = file('kommentar.txt');

    foreach ($titelArray as $index => $title) {

        echo <<<HTML
        <div>

            <h2>
                $title
            </h2>

            <p>
                {$commentArray[$index]}
            </p>

        </div>
        HTML;
    }
}
```

but keep in mind that in case of errors the contents of the files may not match